# Android Navigation Drop down with Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been trying to develop a ListNavigation drop down in action bar. There are 2 drop downs in the action bar. 
[image: Action bar navigation dropdown]

Now I want to display a unique TextView for each spinner selections. 
like If User selects `Fragment1` from left dop down and "one" from right drop down ,a bulleted list of items will go in a TextView. 
If user selects `Fragment 1` from left drop down and "two" from right drop down , another bulleted list of items will be displayed in TextView.

Basically I am using "left drop down" as main menu and "right drop down" as sub-menu to display a text mainly bulleted lists.

Now I am able to get the GUI but i am bit puzzled as to how as to how I can implement this.

Here is the code for Main Activity:

```
    package com.temp.basicactionbar;     

    import java.util.ArrayList;  
    import java.util.HashMap;  
    import java.util.List;  
    import java.util.Map;  

    import android.app.ActionBar;  
    import android.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;  

    import android.app.Activity;  
    import android.app.Fragment;  
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;  
    import android.os.Bundle;  

    import android.view.Menu;  
    import android.view.MenuItem;  
    import android.view.View;  
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;  

    import android.widget.EditText;  
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;  
    import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  
{  
    private MenuItem mSpinnerItem = null;  
    private MenuItem mSearchItem = null;  

    private EditText mSearch = null;  

    @Override  
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {  
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );  

        ActionBar ab = getActionBar();  
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled( false ); 

        setListNavigation( ab );                
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ) {  
        outState.putInt( "mode", getActionBar().getNavigationMode() );  
        super.onSaveInstanceState( outState );  
    }  

    @Override  
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu ) {  
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu );  
        mSpinnerItem = menu.findItem( R.id.menu_spinner );  
        setupSpinner( mSpinnerItem );  
        mSearchItem = menu.findItem( R.id.menu_search );  
        mSearchItem.setVisible(getActionBar().getNavigationMode() == ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS );  
        mSearch = (EditText) mSearchItem.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.search );  

        return true;  
    }  


    private void setListNavigation( ActionBar actionBar )  
    {  
        actionBar.setNavigationMode( ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST );  

        final List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();  

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();  

        map.put( "title", getString( R.string.frag1 ) );  
        map.put( "fragment",  
                Fragment.instantiate( this, Fragment1.class.getName() ) );  
        data.add( map );  

        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
        map.put( "title", getString( R.string.frag2 ) );  
        map.put( "fragment",  
                Fragment.instantiate( this, Fragment2.class.getName() ) );  
        data.add( map );  

        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
        map.put( "title", getString( R.string.frag3 ) );  
        map.put( "fragment",  
                Fragment.instantiate( this, Fragment3.class.getName() ) );  
        data.add( map );  


      map = new HashMap<String, Object>();  

        map.put( "title", getString( R.string.frag4 ) );  

        map.put( "fragment", Fragment.instantiate( this, Fragment4.class.getName() ) );  
        data.add( map );  

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( this, data,  
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,  
                new String[] { "title" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 } );  
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks( adapter,  
                new OnNavigationListener()  
                {  
                    @Override  
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {  
                        Map<String, Object> map = data.get( itemPosition );  
                        Object o = map.get( "fragment" );  
                        if (o instanceof Fragment)  
                        {  
                            FragmentTransaction tx = getFragmentManager()  
                                    .beginTransaction();  
                            tx.replace( android.R.id.content, (Fragment) o );  
                            tx.commit();  
                        }  
                        return true;  
                    }  
                } );  
        if (mSpinnerItem != null)  
        {  
            setupSpinner( mSpinnerItem );  
        }  
    }  

    private void setupSpinner( MenuItem item )  
    {  
        item.setVisible( getActionBar().getNavigationMode() == ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST );  
        View view = item.getActionView();  
        if (view instanceof Spinner)  
        {  
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view;  
            spinner.setAdapter( ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this,  
                    R.array.spinner_data,  
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item ) );  
        }  
    }  

    public void delete( View v )  
    {  
        if (mSearch != null)  
        {  
            mSearch.setText( "" );  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Here is the code for fragments

```
package com.stylingandroid.basicactionbar;  

import android.app.Fragment;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.LayoutInflater;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.ViewGroup;  

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment  
{  
    @Override  
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  
            Bundle savedInstanceState )  
    {  
        return inflater.inflate( R.layout.frag2, container, false );  
    }  
}
```

Here is the XML layout for each frag.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
                android:layout_width="match_parent"  
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >  

    <TextView  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"  
            android:text="@string/frag3"/>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want the complete project zip , please let me know and i will provide it for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did (and I believe this is a good way to go about it), was to use `spinner.onItemSelectedListener()`

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                int i, long lng) {
            if (i == 0) {  // If the first item is selected (usually the default, unless you define another one in code) 
                // Do something here            
            } else if (i == 1) { // Second item selected
                // Do something else...
            } else if (i == 2) {
                // And so on...
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    });
```

And then create a function to update the second spinner with a new array of values.

Alternatively (the easy, but perhaps not the best way), you could create all the spinners in the xml layout, and use the first one to decide which of the second spinners to display (using `setVisibility(View.GONE/View.VISIBLE)`)...

## Update (followup to comment):

To clarify - what I meant about creating all the spinners in the layout, was that you create one spinner for each alternative list, but set the `android:visibility` property to `gone` for all but the one you want the user to see initially.

Then you have to some xml in your layout that goes something like this:

```
<spinner
    android:id="mySpinner1"
    ...
    // properties and stuff here
    ...
    android:visibility="visible" /> // You don't really need this line, since spinners are visible by default

<spinner
    android:id="mySpinner2"
    ...
    // properties and stuff here
    ...
    android:visibility="gone" /> // This line will make it look like the spinner was never there

<spinner
    android:id="mySpinner3"
    ...
    // properties and stuff here
    ...
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

For every spinner you want, and when the user selects something different in the first spinner, you just hide the previous one and display the new one according to his/her choice, using `spinner1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Then the code in the previous example could be modified to something like this (if you have 3 spinners, if you have more or less, you'll have to add the lines for them as well):

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                int i, long lng) {
            if (i == 0) {  // If the first item is selected (usually the default, unless you define another one in code) 
                        // Display the spinner you selected
                spinner1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);           
                        // Hide the rest
                        spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        spinner3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (i == 1) { // Second item selected
                        // Display the spinner you selected
                spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        // Hide the rest
                        spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        spinner3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (i == 2) {
                        // Display the spinner you selected
                spinner3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        // Hide the rest
                        spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    });
```

Note that this is probably not the best way to do it - but hey, it works! ;)

Of course you will have to retrieve the spinners like all other views you want to interact with (by using `findItemById`), but you probably already knew that - good luck with your project.

Comment: Alternatively (the easy, but perhaps not the best way), you could create all the spinners in the xml layout, and use the first one to decide which of the second spinners to display (using setVisibility(View.GONE/View.VISIBLE))..---------------**Can you please explain this ?Sorry but I dont understand. Can you please explain what modification can i make in my layout?? Also what modifications do i need to make in my code**. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi ToVine, i really appreciate your help in resolving my problems.I still am not able to compile my code. Can you please let me know if there is any issue with my project- https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=ECA41FB04BAECC12!213&authkey=!AP2AwsGPSng1owg.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have much time to do it right now - up to my neck in exams... :/